# Find max value in a column that contain -Inf and NA values while using dplyr and tidyR functions

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data frame that looks like this and I want to find the max value in the col1 using
dplyr functions such as slice_n and top_n

```
df = data.frame(col1=c(-Inf, 10,NaN, NA,200,Inf), col2=c(30,30, 10,200,20,10))
 col1 col2
  -Inf   30
    10   30
   NaN   10
    NA  200
   200   20
   Inf   10
```

So far I have not managed this and I was wondering if the community could help me or show me a tip. I highly appreciate your time

Comment: what's your expected output for this sample?

Comment: 200 the max value of col1  :)

Comment: `df %>% filter(!is.na(col1) & !col1 %in% c(Inf, -Inf)) %>% slice_max(col1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the maximum non-infinite value of in `col1`:

```
df %>% 
  filter(!is.infinite(col1)) %>% 
  summarise(Max=max(col1, na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
  pull(Max)

[1] 200
```

Or

```
max(df$col1[!is.infinite(df$col1)], na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 200
```

To find the row containing the maximum non-infinite value in `col1`:

```
df %>% filter(!is.infinite(col1)) %>% slice_max(col1) 
  col1 col2
1  200   20
```

The calls to `filter()` are in response to OP's indication that they require a non-infinte value to be returned.  If infinite values are are acceptable, simply omit the calls.  Note that `slice_max` et al, as requested by OP in their question, do not return *values from the column* but rather *rows from the data frame*.

Note that `top_n()` is superseded.

Answer (score 0):

```
df %>% gather() %>% group_by(key) %>% slice_max(value)
```

Comment: `gather` is retired.  `pivot_longer` is now recommended.

Comment: Does this function give you as an output 200?

Comment: Yes, Inf and 200